# Create table which shows earliest and latest date for same names(IDs)

Tags: sql

So from my table where I have columns: *name, date*

I would like to select names that repeat point out how many times they repeat and then from the rows with same names I want to print out earlies and latest date for that name.

After all my table would have columns: *name, how many, earliest date, latest date*

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    COUNT(name) AS ilosc, 
    MIN(createdDate) as earliest date, 
    MAX(createdDate) AS latest date
FROM Clients
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name)>1
WHERE name IS NOT NULL;
```

I am not sure though if MIN and MAX functions will take into consideration values only from places with the same name or they will take into consideration all the fields.

Do I need to add additional WHERE statements for MIN and MAX functions so they only choose fields with the same names?

sample database that I will be using is:

```
(NULL,'20160101 20:36:12'),
('MARK','20160101 20:38:27'),
('BOB','20160101 20:39:02'),
('MARK','20160101 20:41:55'),
('MARK','20160101 20:42:31'),
('MARK','20160101 20:51:11'),
('MARK','20160101 20:51:24'),
(NULL,'20160101 20:52:01'),
('BOB','20160101 20:53:07'),
('BOB','20160101 20:53:44'),
('KATE','20160101 20:54:52'),
(NULL,'20160101 20:54:57'),
('JOEL','20160101 20:54:59'),
(NULL,'20160101 20:55:03'),
(NULL,'20160101 20:56:12'),
('KATE','20160101 20:57:22'),
('JOEL','20160101 20:58:31'),
('JOEL','20160101 20:59:41'),
('JOEL','20160101 21:02:02'),
('JOEL','20160101 21:03:59'),
('MARK','20160101 21:42:31'),
('MARK','20160101 21:51:11'),
('MARK','20160101 21:51:24')
```

Comment: Aggregate functions apply collectively to all rows in the same group. If you aren't getting the result you expect then ask about that specifically.

Comment: First of all I should most likely use SELECT DISTINCT, but I still don't know how to filter MIn and MAX functions to go over the fields with the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the correctly formed query looks like:

```
SELECT name, 
       COUNT(*) AS ilosc, 
       MIN(createdDate) as earliest_date, 
       MAX(createdDate) as latest_date
FROM Klienci
WHERE name IS NOT NULL;
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Notes:

- The `WHERE` clause goes immediately after the `FROM` clause.  The ordering of clauses is important.
- Column aliases cannot have spaces unless you wrap them in escape characters.  Just use an underscore.
- Although `count(name)` is fine, `count(*)` is more convenient for just counting rows.

As for your question:  The aggregation functions only return values based on rows that match the group.  If you wanted overall numbers, you could use window functions in combination with them:

```
SELECT name, 
       COUNT(*) AS ilosc, 
       MIN(createdDate) as earliest_date, 
       MAX(createdDate) as latest_date,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as total_count,
       MIN(MIN(createdDate)) OVER () as oeverall_earlest_date,
       MAX(MAX(createdDate)) OVER () as oeverall_latest_date
FROM Klienci
WHERE name IS NOT NULL;
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Note that the "overall" numbers are only for the rows that are not filtered out by the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. One more question, shouldn't I use SELECT DISTINCT if I want to only get names without repetitions?

Comment: @S0ul3r . . . That is unnecessary with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will be processed like that:

Filter out all columns where `NAME` is null:

```
('MARK','20160101 20:38:27'),
('BOB','20160101 20:39:02'),
('MARK','20160101 20:41:55'),
('MARK','20160101 20:42:31'),
('MARK','20160101 20:51:11'),
('MARK','20160101 20:51:24'),
('BOB','20160101 20:53:07'),
('BOB','20160101 20:53:44'),
('KATE','20160101 20:54:52'),
('JOEL','20160101 20:54:59'),
('KATE','20160101 20:57:22'),
('JOEL','20160101 20:58:31'),
('JOEL','20160101 20:59:41'),
('JOEL','20160101 21:02:02'),
('JOEL','20160101 21:03:59'),
('MARK','20160101 21:42:31'),
('MARK','20160101 21:51:11'),
('MARK','20160101 21:51:24')
```

Now sort by name and date, grouping by name:

```
('BOB','20160101 20:39:02'),
('BOB','20160101 20:53:07'),
('BOB','20160101 20:53:44'),

('JOEL','20160101 20:54:59'),
('JOEL','20160101 20:58:31'),
('JOEL','20160101 20:59:41'),
('JOEL','20160101 21:02:02'),
('JOEL','20160101 21:03:59'),

('KATE','20160101 20:54:52'),
('KATE','20160101 20:57:22'),

('MARK','20160101 20:38:27'),
('MARK','20160101 20:41:55'),
('MARK','20160101 20:42:31'),
('MARK','20160101 20:51:11'),
('MARK','20160101 20:51:24'),
('MARK','20160101 21:42:31'),
('MARK','20160101 21:51:11'),
('MARK','20160101 21:51:24')
```

Within each group, it will count the number of rows and identify the minimum and maximum date:

```
('BOB','20160101 20:39:02'),  count=1 min=20:39:02
('BOB','20160101 20:53:07'),  count=2 
('BOB','20160101 20:53:44'),  count=3 max=20:53:44

('JOEL','20160101 20:54:59'), count=1 min=20:54:59
('JOEL','20160101 20:58:31'), count=2
('JOEL','20160101 20:59:41'), count=3
('JOEL','20160101 21:02:02'), count=4
('JOEL','20160101 21:03:59'), count=5 max=21:03:59

('KATE','20160101 20:54:52'), count=1 min=20:54:52
('KATE','20160101 20:57:22'), count=2 max=20:57:22

('MARK','20160101 20:38:27'), count=1 min=20:38:27
('MARK','20160101 20:41:55'), count=2
('MARK','20160101 20:42:31'), count=3
('MARK','20160101 20:51:11'), count=4
('MARK','20160101 20:51:24'), count=5
('MARK','20160101 21:42:31'), count=6
('MARK','20160101 21:51:11'), count=7
('MARK','20160101 21:51:24')  count=8 max=21:51:24
```

It can now output name, count, min and max for each group:

```
NAME   COUNT   MIN       MAX
BOB        3   20:39:02  20:53:44
JOEL       5   20:54:59  21:03:59
KATE       2   20:54:52  20:57:22
MARK       8   20:38:27  21:51:24
```